# How can I modify this countdown to not go below zero?

Tags: php, time

I have a PHP page which just makes a countdown to a date and time. Once it hits 0, it currently goes to negative time. How can I modify this code so that when it hits 0 it outputs "SomeText" instead?

```
<?php
    $rem = strtotime('2014-07-26 01:00:00') - time();
    $day = floor($rem / 86400);
    $hr  = floor(($rem % 86400) / 3600);
    $min = floor(($rem % 3600) / 60);
    $sec = ($rem % 60);
    if($day) echo "$day Days ";
    if($hr) echo "$hr Hours ";
    if($min) echo "$min Minutes ";
    if($sec) echo "$sec Seconds ";
?>
```

Comment: `if( $rem===0 ){ echo "we're done!";} else{ echo 'your current echoes';}`

Comment: And what if rem is less than zero, @Martijn?

Comment: Sorry, Im Kinda New To PHP and all. Would I Put all my other echo's in the elce. Like where you have 'your current echoes'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I’ve just added a test to check whether the time remaining (`$rem`) is greater than zero. If so, proceed as before; otherwise output the text you requested.

I have also slightly tidied the code to fit *my* coding style.

```
<?php
    $rem = strtotime('2014-07-26 01:00:00') - time();
    if ($rem > 0) {
        $day = floor($rem / 86400);
        $hr  = floor(($rem % 86400) / 3600);
        $min = floor(($rem % 3600) / 60);
        $sec = ($rem % 60);
        if ($day) {
            echo $day . ' Days ';
        }
        if ($hr) {
            echo $hr . ' Hours ';
        }
        if ($min) {
            echo $min . ' Minutes ';
        }
        if ($sec) {
            echo $sec . ' Seconds ';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Some text';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Ah. You spotted my deliberate mistake, did you? \*cough\* Fixed now.

Comment: You did it! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Everything blank implies a syntax error. There are tools which will scan for syntax errors (`php -l` on the command line, for example); or you can set your web server to output informative error messages instead of blank whiteness (useful for development; not recommended in production). Good luck with learning the language!